# Hi, I am having problems with getting through to a site using DDos protection by cloudflare, when using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, ddos

I am planning to set up an automated prosess on a website. But cant get through the message 'Checking your browser before accessing sit.no' when I try to reach the site using selenium. The message is from cloudflare.

I have been trying some code that i found here but it didnt work

```
1.
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.sit.no/'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

2. 
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.sit.no/'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

3. 
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
url = 'https://www.sit.no/'
driver= uc.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import subprocess
#other imports

subprocess.Popen(
    '"C:\\Program Files\\yourpathtochrome\\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222', shell=True)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.sit.no/')

input()
```

first open the website manually and complete the browser check. now Close all chrome browsers and replace the path with your chrome.exe path. This will work ,

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import subprocess
#other imports

subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222', shell=True)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.sit.no/')`

Comment: Escape forward slash , use the code as it is

Comment: Where? and how does i get the code format?

Comment: What is the issue you facing with the code ?

Comment: [21832:11036:0316/152859.167:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Ingen tilgang. (0x5)
[21832:11036:0316/152859.167:ERROR:cache_util.cc(144)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\sigur\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\sigur\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[21832:11036:0316/152859.167:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[21832:11036:0316/152859.167:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2

Comment: update your selenium and chromedriver to correct versions if they are not

Comment: It opens the chrome browser when I run it, but then it dosent continue.

Comment: You should close all the chrome browsers before running your script

Comment: Once the chrome browser opens , open firefoz and try navigating to localhost:9222, and see devtools open

Comment: Else close everything and change that remote debugging port to something else and run

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked now. Can I just ask you one last question? How do I get the code format in the comments?

Comment: you already did that , its the only way you cannot format it other than , that . You should edit the question and add that i updated the code as mentioned but still not working

Comment: Could you please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign